# Renaming git tags results in inconsistency

Tags: git, git-tag

After renaming a git tag "1.0" to "1.5" with

```
git tag 1.5 1.0
git tag -d 1.0
git push origin :refs/tags/1.0
```

my git repository seems to be in an inconsistent state. Here is the `git describe` output:

```
warning: tag '1.0' is really '1.5' here
1.0-97-g88085b2
```

it should return `1.5-...` now

the `git fsck --tags` output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
tagged commit aad9477bba4bcf44ea34ea9693aeffc98527ff01 (1.0) in b96ce67583239e198f9e2aff5175176d65779044
Checking objects: 100% (3975/3975), done.
```

How can I remove the dangling reference to the deleted tag? Is this the right way for renaming tags?

Comment: Honestly, I tried and tried but couldn't reproduce your dangling tag.   Your procedure at the top seems to be a standard way to rename tags, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've run into the same issue a few minutes ago. None of the answers already presented dealt with the **real issue** which is getting rid of the message `warning: tag 'foo' is really 'bar' here` and getting `git describe` to just list the new name of the tag. This was especially important in my case, as my build system uses `git describe` to record into the build what sources were used to make the build.

#### Replicating the Problem

I can replicate the issue by doing this:

```
$ git tag foo --annotate -m"original message"
$ git tag bar foo
$ git tag -d foo
$ git describe 
warning: tag 'foo' is really 'bar' here
foo
```

(The `--annotate` flag above is redundant as `-m` implies `--annotate`, but I've included it for emphasis.) I've tried to replicate the problem with a lightweight tag but was not able to do so. So to replicate the issue, an annotation is necessary.

#### Fixing the Problem

Some of this involves pushing over things that have peen pushed already but I find myself in agreement with David Culp when [he says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381774/1906307):

> However, there are times it just isn't worth the long-term pain of an inaccurate (messy) history and the short-term pain is worth it.

Once you are stuck with the `warning: tag 'foo' is really 'bar' here`, then you must do:

```
$ git tag bar bar -m"original message" --force
$ git describe 
bar
```

Adapt as needed if the message needs changing.

To delete the old tag if it was already pushed:

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/foo
```

To update the new tag if it was already pushed:

```
$ git push origin refs/tags/bar
```

#### Avoiding the Problem

To avoid the problem in the first place you'd have to create `bar` with:

```
$ git tag bar foo -m"original message"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Works great! This answer should be accepted as it is the only one which solves (!) the original problem.

Comment: If you do `git tag bar bar -m"original message" --force`, then you can simply do a `git push --force origin refs/tags/bar` afterwards, no need to delete. In fact a delete will delete your updated tag and you can't push it anymore afterwards.

Comment: But this will change the date of the updated tag, right?

Comment: Worth noting: the message `tag '%s' is really '%s' here"` comes out of `git describe` and applies only to annotated tags, which is why you must start with an annotated tag to reproduce the problem. This stems from the internal implementation: an annotated tag is actually a pair of entities, which should match, and using `git tag <new-name> <existing-annotated-tag>` creates one new non-matching entity (a lightweight tag *name*) for the existing annotated tag *object* that embeds the old name.

Comment: This in turn is why you must make a new *pair* (new lightweight tag of name X pointing to annotated tag of name X). The underlying annotated object named X can point either directly to the same commit object that the original annotated tag used, or to the original annotated tag object itself. To point directly to the underlying object rather than the old tag, use `git tag bar foo^{} -m "..."`: the `^{}` suffix means "resolve tag to underlying object".

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate the standard caution whenever someone suggests rewriting history (or in this instance, retagging history) -- if you can avoid it, don't do it.

However, there are times it just isn't worth the long-term pain of an inaccurate (messy) history and the short-term pain is worth it.

If that is the case, the following article gives the steps needed: [How to Rename a Tag Already Pushed to a Remote git Repo](http://blog.sidmitra.com/how-to-rename-a-tag-already-pushed-to-a-remot).

Basic steps are:

```
git tag new_tag old_tag
git push --tags
git push origin :refs/tags/old_tag
git tag -d old_tag
```

Comment: Is here a way to remove a "1.0" tag completely from the git history in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful this will be, but I ran into this warning while using [release-it](https://github.com/release-it/release-it).  In my remote repo, there were both lightweight and annotated tag entries for the same tag name:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags origin
302883ef0cb2df8975abfbd24bbe89f64cf3da31    refs/tags/0.0.1
4852192308b404d74d7a4088c19a4629299f6ea2    refs/tags/0.0.1^{}
```

(Note the `^{}` after the tag name on the second entry)

This appears to be normal for annotated tags (?), so don't think that's the problem per se, but the problem went away after I deleted all the tags and retagged everything.  E.g. for the above tag...

```
git tag -d 0.0.1                # Delete local tag
git push --delete origin 0.0.1  # Delete remote tag
git tag -a -m "" 0.0.1 4852192308b404d74d7a4088c19a4629299f6ea2  # Recreate [annotated] tag
git push --tags                 # Push tag(s) to remote repo
```

Answer (score -3):

No, I don't think this is the proper workflow for tags in git.

A fundamental rule of git is:  **Don't mess with something you've already pushed.**

Since you've already pushed tag 1.0, you do not want to be renaming it to 1.5 locally and then trying to push it.  Leave the 1.0 tag for posterity, create a new 1.5 tag, and push that, too.   And really- that's what tags are for.  So you can go back 6 months from now and recreate what your software was like at version 1.0.

Comment: Well, the initial commit was tagged with "1.0" but actually it should be tagged as "1.5". Therefore my attempt to rename it.

Comment: While that is generally a good rule of thumb, there is no reason that you shouldn't be able to do what he was trying to do as long as nobody else has pulled